# Option Strict On no permite el enlace en tiempo de ejecución VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, listbox

tengo un **`listBox`** con datos, y al momento de dar doble click en un item , éste se transala a una caja de texto, con **`Option Strict Off`**, este código funciona correctamente.

```
Private Sub lbNoRemisiones_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles lbNoRemisiones.MouseDoubleClick
   frmRegistroPolycom.txtRemision.Text = lbNoRemisiones.SelectedItem(0).ToString
        Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Ahora con **`Option Strict On`**
Me marca error

> Option Strict On no permite el enlace en tiempo de ejecución

```
frmRegistroPolycom.txtRemision.Text = lbNoRemisiones.SelectedItem(0).ToString
```

más que corregirlo, me gustaría entender del porque me marca el error, Saludos!!

A C T U A L I Z A C I O N

He considerado que el error podria ser por la forma en que cargo el ListBox. Esta es la manera en que lo hago.

```
Sub LlenarListBox()
        Dim dts As New vpolycom
        Dim func As New fpolycom
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Try
            dts.g_remision = RTrim(txtBNoRemision.Text)
            dt = func.filtrarSeries(dts)
            If dt.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                lbNoRemisiones.DataSource = dt
                lbNoRemisiones.DisplayMember = "rem_folio_doc"
            Else
                lbNoRemisiones.DataSource = Nothing
            Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message & " Error !", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Excepcion")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: y ya leiste esto: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement

Comment: El enlace de @gbianchi es relevante. Aun así, debo tener un poco oxidado el vb pq no veo late binding en ese código, estás seguro de que el error es ahi?

Comment: ...a no ser que el DataSource de `lbNoRemisiones` este definido como un Array sin tipo por ejemplo. Puedes poner la definicion del enumerable que asignas a `lbNoRemisiones`?

Comment: yo tengo el mismo problema... es mas esta pasando un string a un string.. salvo.. que sean de diferentes formularios...

Comment: @Pikoh son diferentes formularios.. sera por eso?

Comment: @Pikoh despues de esa asignacion, cierra el form donde esta.. creeme, son diferentes formularios ;)

Comment: @gbianchi a veces tienes razon. Son dos formularios diferentes. Pero yo dudo que tenga nada que ver. Resumiendo, necesitaríamos mas información para ver donde está el problema

Comment: Late-binding, call could faild at runtime.. deberia verificar antes de pasar el valor al form que no sea null.. fijate si no viene por ahi...

Comment: @gbianchi eso sería un null exception en todo caso. Esperaremos a ver si el OP nos aclara un poco el tema

Comment: No se si sea relevante, en esta linea lbNoRemisiones.SelectedItem() quitando el 0, me corre el programa y al realizar la operación en la caja de texto me aparece System.Data.DataRow.View

Comment: @Pikoh he actualizado la pregunta, anexando la forma de llenar el listBox, podría ser el problema. He verificado llenando un ListBox desde su propiedad item y con un lbNoRemisiones.SelectedItem() va perfecto, por lo que el error considero puede venir de atrás.